# Fill out JSON file from pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

**TLDR** I got JSON file with data about exercises, I parsed it added custom data and filled out the template JSON but to my surprise, my template wasn't filled out with different rows but with multiple copies of one row.

How can I populate my template with values from each row. One row one template.

```
{
 "exercises": [
    {
      "name": "3/4 Sit-Up",
      "force": "pull",
      "level": "beginner",
      "mechanic": "compound",
      "equipment": "body only",
      "primaryMuscles": [
        "abdominals"
      ],
      "secondaryMuscles": [],
      "instructions": [
        "Lie down on the floor and secure your feet. Your legs should be bent at the knees.",
        "Place your hands behind or to the side of your head. You will begin with your back on the ground. This will be your starting position.",
        "Flex your hips and spine to raise your torso toward your knees.",
        "At the top of the contraction your torso should be perpendicular to the ground. Reverse the motion, going only Â¾ of the way down.",
        "Repeat for the recommended amount of repetitions."
      ],
      "category": "strength"
    },
    {
      "name": "90/90 Hamstring",
      "force": "push",
      "level": "beginner",
      "mechanic": null,
      "equipment": "body only",
      "primaryMuscles": [
        "hamstrings"
      ],
      "secondaryMuscles": [
        "calves"
      ],
      "instructions": [
        "Lie on your back, with one leg extended straight out.",
        "With the other leg, bend the hip and knee to 90 degrees. You may brace your leg with your hands if necessary. This will be your starting position.",
        "Extend your leg straight into the air, pausing briefly at the top. Return the leg to the starting position.",
        "Repeat for 10-20 repetitions, and then switch to the other leg."
      ],
      "category": "stretching"
    }]
}
```

I've imported this to pandas df with only 3 values that are important to me

```
with open('exercises.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ['exercises'])

parsed_df = df[['name', 'category']]
parsed_df.loc[:, 'authorized'] = True
```

Then I've created my template and loaded in to the script

```
{
    "model": "myapp.exercise",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "name": "",
      "category": "",
      "authorized": "" 
    }
}
```

```
with open('template.json','r') as f:
    data_template = json.loads(f.read())
```

Next I've iterated over each row in my parsed_df to get all the values and fill out copies of template file, then added it to the list

```
dict_list = []

for index, row in parsed_df.iterrows():

    data_template['pk'] = index
    data_template['fields']['name'] = row['name']
    data_template['fields']['category'] = row['category']
    data_template['fields']['authorized'] = row['authorized']
    dict_list.append(data_template)
```

I've printed out row and index value first to be sure that Im seeing different values in each interaction. Everything was great but then I've checked out my dict_list that had multiple copies of the last row in parsed_df

Comment: In the for-loop in each iteration first create a deep copy of the template (see module `copy`) and modify and finally append that copy to `dict_list`. Otherwise you modify and append the same dict again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Michael I've created deep copy in for loop. Now everything runs well.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import copy

with open('exercises.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ['exercises'])

parsed_df = df[['name', 'category']]
parsed_df.loc[:, 'authorized'] = True

with open('template.json','r') as f:
    data_template = json.loads(f.read())

dict_list = []

for index, row in parsed_df.iterrows():
    new_template = copy.deepcopy(data_template)
    new_template['pk'] = index
    new_template['fields']['name'] = row['name']
    new_template['fields']['category'] = row['category']
    new_template['fields']['authorized'] = row['authorized']
    dict_list.append(new_template)

    
output_file = open('converted.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
for dic in dict_list:
    json.dump(dic, output_file) 
    output_file.write("\n")
```